# Syntax for JSTL Ternary with variable

Tags: java, html, jsp, jstl

I am trying to figure out the proper syntax for using ternary in JSTL.

The following is what I have

```
value="${(contains == 'false' && facultyMember eq true) ? '${prepTime}' : ''}"/>
```

However when this evaluates to true it does not give the $prepTime variable like I want.

I tried taking the single quotes out from around the variable name like so

```
value="${(contains == 'false' && facultyMember eq true) ? ${prepTime} : ''}"/>
```

however this is also not correct.

any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `${prepTime}` to `prepTime`

```
value="${((contains == 'false') && (facultyMember eq true)) ? prepTime : ''}"/>
```